# Failed audit - what's wrong?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, deleted-answers

Can you tell what is wrong with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21298239)?

Maybe it isn't the correct answer, but it looks okay for me.

Comment: Can you edit in a screenshot?

Comment: I can't see the answer because it is deleted (and I have <10k rep).

Comment: @Codeer I provided a metasmoke link in my answer which contains the raw html of the post in question, but can post a screenshot too if you'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, it looks okay to me. It seems to answer the question, it's roughly the right language. Whether it actually *works* is nothing the review queue is built to judge. The link seems to lead to a reference, not a spam site or something.

Following the link however, it seems like the post is just a copy of the link's content. That's not cool. That's probably a reason for deletion.

That said, I don't follow every single link in a review if there is nothing suspicious to see. I would probably have failed that as well.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a very good audit.

The answer, though, was spam. See [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/139203) for an explanation, the user apparently was posting 20 answers containing plagiarized content to direct traffic to his site.

A general piece of advice: when reviewing an answer containing a link, *always* go to the post, check if the answer fits the question, if so, follow the link. Or just hit skip if you're not knowledgeable. Some spam authors plagiarize good answers, making their answers look very reasonable.

Comment: The purpose of review is to catch spam like this.  That makes it a *good* audit, because if people are missing things like this (even though they aren't trivial to get right) then that's a big problem for review.

Comment: I'm not sure, the context makes this answer spam. If this would've been the only answer of its kind posted by that user, it would've probably just been an OK answer. And moderating users is a mod job, not a user job. But the lesson is: see link in answer and answer looks OK -> check context of answer, and that makes it a sort-of okay audit I guess, because then you see it's an audit.

Comment: In this case the answer is linking to a resource of theirs without disclosing affiliation, so it's actually spam even on its own.  While you might not be able to tell that it's certainly spam from just the review alone, there are several red flags here, red flags that you would want a reviewer to find and investigate further (or raise for a moderator to investigate further).  And in general you should be more on the look for spam in review queues like this one designed to find it than when using the site normally.